# Overlap between two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Given are two vectors ${\bf g}_1, {\bf g}_2\in\mathbb{R}^N$ with non-zero scalar-product ${\bf g}_1^\top{\bf g}_2 \ne 0$. Then there exist three unique (up to the sign) orthonormal unit vectors ${\bf e}_1, {\bf e}_2, {\bf e}_3$ and non-zero scalars $\alpha_i, \beta_i$ such that

$${\bf g}_1 = \alpha_1{\bf e}_1 + \alpha_2{\bf e}_2$$
$${\bf g}_2 = \beta_1{\bf e}_1 + \beta_2{\bf e}_3$$

**Question:** How can I extract the "common direction" ${\bf e}_1$ given just the vectors ${\bf g}_1$ and ${\bf g}_2$?

**Update 1:** The answer by Cave Johnson seems correct in that the decomposition is not unique. To give a concrete toy example, consider

$${\bf g}_1 = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\
0\\
\end{array}
\right), {\bf g}_2 = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
1\\
\end{array}
\right).$$
There are two simple splittings one can make:
$${\bf g}_1 = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
0\\
\end{array}
\right) + \left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1\\
0\\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$${\bf g}_2 = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
0\\
\end{array}
\right) + \left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
1\\
\end{array}
\right)$$
or
$$
\begin{align}
{\bf g}_1 &= \,1\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\
0\\
\end{array}
\right), \\
{\bf g}_2 &= \frac{1}{2}\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\
0\\
\end{array}
\right) + \left(
\begin{array}{c}
1/2\\
-1/2\\
1\\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: The vectors *and* scalars can't be unique.  If you replace $\mathbf e_1$ with $-\mathbf e_1$, then you could just replace $\alpha_1$ and $\beta_1$ with $-\alpha_1$ and $-\beta_1$, respectively.  Maybe they're unique up to sign, though.  Hmm...

Comment: I start to suspect they can't even be unique up to sign and scaling.

Comment: I took down my specious answer. This question is getting more interesting.

Comment: @Bye_World : you are right about the sign, and I updated the description accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a condition that $\mathbf{g}_1, \mathbf{g}_2$ are not parallel is missing in the problem. Given that condition, the problem can be simply reduced to a 3-dimensional one. In fact, $\mathbf{g}_1, \mathbf{g}_2$ span a 2-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Adding a vector orthogonal to this subspace yields a new 3-dimensional subspace, and then we only need to find $\mathbf{e}_1, \mathbf{e}_2, \mathbf{e}_3$ in this subspace.
Now the problem can be solved easily in a geometric way. Take $\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2$ two orthonormal vectors such that $\mathbf{g}_1$ lies in the plane they span, which is denoted by $\Sigma$. Then choose $\mathbf{e}_3$ the unit vector orthogonal to $\Sigma$. Since $\mathbf{g}_1,\mathbf{g}_2$ is not orthogonal, $\mathbf{g}_2$ is not parallel to $\mathbf{e}_3$. One may choose a proper $\beta_2$ such that $\mathbf{g}_2-\beta_2\mathbf{e}_3$ lies in $\Sigma$. Now rotate $\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2$ around the axis $\mathbf{e}_3$ to make $\mathbf{e}_1$ parallel to $\mathbf{g}_2-\beta_2\mathbf{e}_3$. Then we're done. The uniqueness seems not to be true.

Comment: I believe there is a flaw in the geometric argument: there is no guarantee that ${\bf g}_2 - \beta_2{\bf e}_3$ lies in the plane $\Sigma$ since there is no condition that ${\bf g}_2$ is in the subspace spanned by ${\bf e}_1, {\bf e}_2, {\bf e}_3$.

Comment: There is indeed a flaw, but not this one. $\mathbf{g}_2$ should be in the subspace spanned by $\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2,\mathbf{e}_3$ for the argument in the first paragraph: we only consider the problem in 3-dimensions. The case I really omitted is the one where $\mathbf{g}_2$ lies in $\Sigma$ or $\mathbf{g}_1$ is parellel to $\mathbf{g}_2-\beta_2\mathbf{e}_3$. In this case a little rotation of the $\Sigma$ plane around $\mathbf{g}_1$ is needed.

Comment: You are right, the decomposition is not unique. I'll add a concrete toy example to my question. Thanks!